ACC Contract data -- No API to get the tax details
We’ve encountered a critical issue during the mapping of ACC contract data objects to Oracle EBS columns using ACC APIs such as GET_CONTRACTS and GET_Schedule_of_Values. Specifically, the current Cost Management APIs do not fetch tax details, which presents a major challenge.
Without the ability to extract the tax flag, Oracle EBS will automatically calculate tax for all schedule of value lines (PO lines). This creates a significant issue, as we won’t be able to post the calculated tax amount back to ACC from Oracle EBS.
Your prompt assistance with this matter is greatly appreciated, as it is essential to maintaining the integrity of our financial transactions between ACC and Oracle EBS.
Thank you for your attention to this issue.
We are expecting an API from the ACC Product, Need to fetch and post tax details within the contracts or guide us how to get the tax details from ACC product to integrate to Oracle EBS (E-business suite), which is on Onprem.

The API to get Taxes is on the way soon, we are actively working on that to get this released, pay attention to our announcement, if you don't see it in next 1 or 2 months, please contact us for more details.
Btw, do you also want to create taxes for the ACC cost object by API? or just fetching theset taxes from cost object is enough for now?
